# How to handle the error "command "play" not found" while coding a discord bot with python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I tried figuring out a discord python music bot and it works, in some aspects, for example when i tell it to join or disconnect it does it but whenevever i try playing music it tells me that such a command does not exist. Also i put an error handler so it tels me in the terminal and in discord that there is no such a command. The guy that i watched a video from so i can help myself didn't have this problem.

Here is my code:

```
<main.py>
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    #import os
    import music
    
    cogs = [music]
    
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents = discord.Intents.all())
    
    
    
    
    for i in range(len(cogs)):
      cogs[i].setup(client)
    
    @client.event
    async def on_command_error(ctx, error): 
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound): 
            em = discord.Embed(title=f"Error!!!", description=f"Command not found.", color=ctx.author.color) 
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('Bot is on!')
    
    #@client.event
    #async def on_message(message):
        #if message.author == client.user:
            #return
        #if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
            #await message.channel.send('Hello, sir!')
    
    
    client.run('Token here')
    
<music.py>    

    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import youtube_dl
    
    
    class music(commands.Cog):
      def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
      
      
    
        @commands.command()
        async def join(self,ctx):
          if ctx.author.voice is None:
              await ctx.send('You need to be in a vc in order to play music!')
          voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
          if ctx.voice_client is None: 
              await voice_channel.connect()
          else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)  
    
        @commands.command()
        async def disconnect(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    
        @commands.command(name="play")     
        async def play(self,ctx,url):
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
            YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
            vc = ctx.voice_client
    
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL (YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                vc.play(source)
    
        @commands.command()
        async def pausel(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send("Paused")
    
        @commands.command()
        async def resume (self, ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.resume ()
            await ctx.send("Resumed")
    
    
    
    def setup(client):
      client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: Can you provide the video you watched? I see this code a lot and wanna know where it comes from

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer, absolutely! Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM&t=326s

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why adding cogs from another module doesn't work, but you can put the music class in the main.py and add the music class in the cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
#import os
    
    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents = discord.Intents.all())
    

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
      
      
    
  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send('You need to be in a vc in order to play music!')
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None: 
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)  
    
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    
  @commands.command(name="play")     
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL (YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)
    
  @commands.command()
  async def pausel(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused")
    
  @commands.command()
  async def resume (self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume ()
    await ctx.send("Resumed")
    
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): 
  if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound): 
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Error!!!", description=f"Command not found.", color=ctx.author.color) 
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is on!')
    
    
client.add_cog(music(client))
client.run('token')
```

Also, I recommend that you add an alias to the commands, so it won't be a hassle to type the whole command.

Example:

```
@commands.command(name="play", aliases = ["p", "sing"])
```

Try `(prefix)help` to see all the commands of the bot to test that it worked.

Comment: Thank you, sir! That helped a lot! In fact, I succeded in building it finally! :)